Flutter: Git -rev-parse --verify: [Needed single revision.]
I am a bit confused as to why this is happening. I am running flutter upgrade on the mingw64 subsystem from msys2 and it fails every single time with error: Fatal: needed a single revision.
I've proceeded to install git for windows and ran the same command but it is successful.
Nothing has changed other than mingw64 from msys2 and mingw64 from git for windows.
You can see the attached images below.

Git for windows (SUCCESSFUL)

Git from msys2 - mingw64 (FAILED)


Anyone has any idea why this is happening?



Perhaps the git is too old.  @{upstream} is relatively modern.

Confirmed that both are the same version. git --version shows 2.47.1
